# Enable Hibernate in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: hibernate, 18.04

How can I set Hibernation in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (laptop)?

When I open the Power option > When the Power Button is pressed,
I just see the following options:

- Suspend
- Power OFF
- Nothing

But does not show Hibernate.

Comment: Follow this guide-
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-17-10/

Comment: Voting to reopen since in 18.04 things have changed.  The `pm-utils` package is obsolete and power management is now handled by `systemd`.

Comment: @psusi and doesn't the linked post have the systemd solution as well?

Comment: answer in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056326/ubuntu-18-hibernation-using-the-power-button?rq=1

Comment: @Ferroao seems to have been removed, the only remaining answer is now another link.

Answer (score 25):

If you are OK with suspending instead of hibernating, you can try this:

1. Before you click "Power Button" - press "Alt"

   OR
2. Click "Power Button" and hold it.

Comment: Why was this reply down voted? I "plussed" it because it is the simplest answer and it answers the question. By pressing Alt the Power button changes to a "Pause" button; click it again, the computer goes into hibernation.

Comment: This is a good trick to know, but this does not hibernate (suspend to disk) but instead puts the computer to sleep (suspends to RAM)

Comment: This may not answer the question as asked, but compared to the true answers (enabling hibernate in Ubuntu 18.04 is complicated!) it's a partial solution and it's simple.

Comment: you should add as part of the answer that this solution does not hibernates the system, suspends it to avoid confusions.

Comment: This answer doesn't even remotely try to answer this question. Q: "I want to hibernate but I can only suspend" / A: "Here is an alternative way to suspend". Why would anyone vote that up??

Comment: This is suspension (in ram) and not hibernation (on hard drive). This is why I downvoted.

Comment: this will suspend the system, not put the machine into hibernation, it two different methods for the computer to "sleep"

Comment: @SuRa I see you originally made this edit: https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1030657 This is a massive change to the answer, you should have posted it as a separate answer.

Comment: @SuRa I've approved your suggested edit to remove the material you'd added earlier with the intention of posting it as as separate answer instead (and my own review was the second approval, so this caused your edit to be applied). But this question is closed as a duplicate. I'm hoping there's a suitable place for you to post your answer--maybe on the question this is closed as a duplicate of? If you encounter problems posting your answer or finding a place to do so (or if you believe the duplicate closure here is incorrect) and you comment to let me know, then I'll try to look into it further.

Answer (score 20):

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

This did not work for me. I try pm-hibernate which did not work for me either until I added missing package uswsusp

```
sudo apt install uswsusp
```

Comment: What did not work? The blogpost suggestion? If you meant this, then I can confirm it didn't work, though I followed the procedure. Any idea, what went wrong?

Comment: hibernate command was acting like shutdown for me, no windows restored. Then I installed uswsusp and hibernate worked for me just once. Now I see the option in action for power button press and set it too. But now again hibernate acts like shutdown.

Comment: I had the same problem, the hibernate command was acting like shutdown. I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034185/ubuntu-18-04-cant-resume-after-hibernate/1064114#1064114) and now it works!

Comment: I fond other solution it this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053134/hibernation-in-18-04#1053227) which leads to [solution](https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2018/07/14/configuring-lubuntu-18-04-to-enable-hibernation-using-a-swap-file/)

Answer (score 12):

Use this, it is more recent. It worked for me with a new 18.04 install on my laptop.
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/

Also, check that you have a swap file before you start. You should have one by default. Run

```
swapon --show
```

to check.