# Cannot enter hibernation through hibernate, pm-hibernate or gnome button. Computer hangs

Tags: 18.04, crash, hibernate, system

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Macbook pro 11,3

When pausing with the Gnome alt+shutdown button, or entering command `sudo pm-hibernate`, screen becomes black but the machine is not completely turned off. Pressing a button after a while may display the mouse arrow or Ubuntu Gnome desktop but it is frozen.
`sudo hibernate` is quite similar leaving a message on black screen saying s2disk is writing image but it never finishes. I can input characters though.
With `sudo s2disk` I get black screen but machine is not shutdown.
In any cases the machine won't completely turn off and I have to hard shutdown.

I have also tried with the proprietary driver of nVidia, no change.

Swap partition is active and bigger than the 16GB ram.
Could this issue be related to hardware, although I have no problem with suspending to disk from Windows or MacOS on the same machine ?

I would appreciate any help to solve this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, pm-hibernate started working for me after installing

```
sudo apt install uswsusp
```

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031633/enable-hibernate-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

then using pm-hibernate