# Hibernation in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, hibernate

**Hibernation** on my Ubuntu 18.04 did not work out of the box (I mean `sudo systemctl hibernate`). So I made several attempts to fix that some time ago and unfortunately can not remember exactly what I did.

But now:

```
sudo hibernate
```

successfully hibernates the system and on the next boot the system state successfully restores, except for the login screen does not appear, which is not good. And if I have many applications running than after such a resume the system might be frozen for up to 20 minutes (I see applications' windows, can move mouse pointer, but the system does not respond to clicks) but after that works normally.

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

does something, shuts down the system, but on the next boot I see several messages **delete orphaned node** and finally clean boot, as if there were no hibernation.

Please help me clear it up and enable hibernation in the gui interface.

At the same time suspend to memory and resume from memory works fine without a problem, *including the login screen on resume*.

The primary question I have is: Which of the two mechanisms `hibernate` or `systemctl hibernate` should I use with 18.04?

**Details**

The system has swap partition

```
$ lsblk | grep SWAP
└─sda5   8:5    0  16,8G  0 part [SWAP]
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15894        3386        9945        1311        2561       11848
Swap:         17163        2150       15013
```

and in `/etc/default/grub` it has

**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/sda5"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""**

and

```
$ cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem disk
$ cat /sys/power/disk
[platform] shutdown reboot suspend test_resume
```

### [SOLVED] :-)

Finally I managed to bring hibernation to work. As long as I do not have deep understanding of the subject, I'd rather describe what I did. So

1. Completely removed **pm-utils** and **uswsusp**, then `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all` and `reboot`

After this hibernation attempt ended up in clean boot instead of resume. So then

2. Reinstalled **systemd** then changed device names to UUIDs so as

in `/etc/default/grub`

**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=2c8ec945-6967-4538-93ef-49eb4df6f2a1"**

in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

**RESUME=UUID=2c8ec945-6967-4538-93ef-49eb4df6f2a1**

then

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
$ sudo update-grub
$ reboot
```

After this `sudo systemctl hibernate` and resume succeeded but without login screen, so

3. In **Settings** (gui) for power button action I assigned "Hibernate"

Now when I press power button the system hibernates and then restores through login screen.

**Many thanks to everyone involved**

---

**UPD: Now I have found an even better solution - use swap file**

I verified this on fresh Ubuntu 18.10 desktop install and suppose it to work with fresh 18.04 desktop install too as they both use swap *file* by default i.e. they do not allocate swap *partition* by default. But the default swap file is 2Gb regardless of the system memory size, so it should be increased.

The complete description is for example [here](https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2018/07/14/configuring-lubuntu-18-04-to-enable-hibernation-using-a-swap-file/).

Comment: Hi Sergey K , and welcome to askUbuntu! Please add more information to your post how and what you tried to run hibernation!

Comment: Hibernation (save system state to disk, then poweroff) is disabled-by-default in Ubuntu precisely because it is unreliable on some manufacturers' hardware. If enabling results in problems, consider simply disabling it again. While the problem might be a setting or a software bug, it might also be in BIOS or proprietary hardware interfaces at kernel-level. Much of the low-hanging fruit has been fixed  already.

Comment: I have the same problem. Systemd hibernate is broken, but the old-fashioned `pm-hibernate` works.

Comment: Could You post Your solution as an answer and mark it as solution? It may help someone find it easier.

Comment: Tk, managed to get it working.. except I don't have "Hybernate" on Settings for the power button.. how yo ugot it?

Comment: "Hibernate" on Settings for the power button just appears after you configure the hibernation.

Comment: answer in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056326/ubuntu-18-hibernation-using-the-power-button?rq=1

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the answer is not found in the other questions. Please unmark it!

Answer (score 14):

There's two excellent answers to hibernation questions with a bit more detail here:

**Little Ancient Forest Kami**'s answer to : [Ubuntu 18.04 can't resume after hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034185/ubuntu-18-04-cant-resume-after-hibernate/1038856#1038856)

**Zanna**'s answer to : [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04/821122#821122)

I don't normally use Hibernate but was attempting to use it recently whilst chasing down a bug and realised that in order to work on 18.04 you need to add a line to /etc/default/grub to tell it where to resume from.

*On 16.04 it wasn't necessary for me to add the 'resume=' parameter to grub, so I think the change has happened relatively recently.*

You're probably best to use the UUID (Universally Unique Identifier) and can use the 'Disks' program to find out the UUID of your swap partition and just copy and paste it from there.

Use `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` to add to the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

so that it has the extra kernel parameter `resume=UUID=theUUIDofyourswappartition` in between the quotes.

Yours will be different, but in my case the line is:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=549816d3-0ed8-44fa-a7e4-968db519a141"
```

*(exit nano using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, press <kbd>y</kbd> to make the changes and <kbd>enter</kbd> to accept the filename)*

You need to run `sudo update-grub` to make your changes effective, but when you next reboot you should be able to hibernate without problems.

**As far as I'm aware, the functionality of hibernate is to resume to where you left off, so is not designed to go to the login screen and ask for your password.**

I don't know if you can change it so that it will ask for your password, but it might be worth asking a separate question to see if someone else knows what to do.

---

#### Swapfile

If you have a swapfile instead of a separate swap partition then you also need to add the extra `resume_offset=` parameter.

The Arch Linux Wiki has [a great section on this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#About_swap_partition.2Ffile_size) but basically your swap file should be on the main partition that you have Ubuntu installed on.

In order to find out the offset to put in `resume_offset=` you can open a terminal and type

```
sudo filefrag -v /swapfile
```

you'll get something that looks like this:

```
ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..   32767:      34816..     67583:  32768:            
   1:    32768..   63487:      67584..     98303:  30720:            
   2:    63488..   96255:     100352..    133119:  32768:      98304:
   3:    96256..  126975:     133120..    163839:  30720:   
etc...
```

and you want the first number, in the first line that's under `physical_offset` (in this case `34816`)

So just as an example, using the UUID and physical offset of my machine with a Swapfile, I've changed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` line to be

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=09e601cd-5bac-491a-9115-fda1b2eb4664 resume_offset=34816"
```

Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` and reboot, but after that hibernate should work correctly.

Comment: [This answer of mine on AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04/821122#821122) has that info, which I got from the incomparable [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#About_swap_partition.2Ffile_size).

Comment: @Zanna - thanks for tidying up my messy answer (I've not quite got the hang of formatting extended code snippets yet :) ) I think you're right - I must have got the info from the Arch Linux wiki but I was searching about in the Ubuntu documentation and couldn't find the 'physical_offset' references I was looking for. I'll update my answer with references to the Arch wiki and your answer.

Comment: No problem! You did a decent job - the formatting definitely takes time to get used to. Seems like this isn't working for OP(?) but might help others. I'm still struggling with hibernation on my machine with every change to the kernels I use :/

Comment: thanks, the `filefrag` command saved my life!

Comment: Worked for me like a charm with swap partition