# hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found

Tags: dual-boot, hibernate

I am a newbie with Ubuntu and running a dual boot with windows 10 and ubuntu 18, i tried installing hibernate by doing

```
"apt-get install hibernate"
```

but when i try

```
sudo hibernate
```

the screen goes off for a few seconds then i get the following error

```
hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found.
```

Comment: wow...not a single response after 8 hours !

Comment: I get the same.

Comment: My laptop can hibernate just fine, but after resuming I also see this warning.  Maybe it's not the real problem, as the answer below suggests.

Answer (score 2):

I can only say that this warning doesn't necessary mean that hibernation will not succeed. For me hibernation works even though the warning is displayed. Why it doesn't work in Your case may be a matter of other issues. For example, if I'm not wrong, it may be connected with size of Your SWAP partition (if nothing changed in the meantime, it is recommended to be a size of You RAM memory I believe) or GRUB configuration (boot options).

For the start I would recommend trying some other programs like `pm-hibernate`. If I were You, I would also check out this question: [Hibernation in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053134/hibernation-in-18-04#1053227) (which seems to contain solution in the answer, hmm...) or this one: [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04) and try to search for more if needed.

And, by the way, I believe it does not really have much to do with dual booting.

Comment: @chrisgeeq, wow, I just discovered that this question is 3 months old! Sad that no one answered before. I hope You solved it already or this answer will help You in any way.

Comment: `pm-hibernate` doesn't work hence the need to install `hibernate`. I had this work once but don't remember what I changed now it only gives me this error and won;t hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a clarifying comment than an answer.  The text of the error is arguably a bug in of itself:

```
hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found.
```

Here the programmer has attempted to warn users that a file seems to missing.  But the programmer has left out an essential piece of data, specifically **the name of that file**.

---

The program itself must know, so it's not like the error message couldn't say something like:

```
hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file "/foo/bar/baz123" not found.
```

...which would enable the user to make progress by checking if the file *baz123* existed, and was in the correct location, had the correct permissions, and had reasonable contents.

Note:  After running `hibernate`, (which worked, *Linux Mint v20.2*), I encountered this vague error message today, three years after the Q. was first posted.

Comment: If it is a comment, why has it been posted as an answer? Also, LM is not Ubuntu, which makes it off topic.

Comment: @mikewhatever, *LM v20.2* is based on [*Ubuntu v20.4 LTS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint#Releases).  Re *answer*:  improving the definition of the nature of a problem, (negligent vagueness), helps to reduce the size of the solution set.