# ubuntu 18 hibernation using the power button

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, swap, hibernate

I am using ubuntu 18, I had issues using hibernation

```
systemctl-hibernate 
pm-hibernate
```

setting the power button to hibernate, 
dconf-editor, 
alt+power button,
and gnome extentions did not work

It started working after I used

```
sudo apt install uswsusp
```

Now only pm-hibernate works, non of the others including systemctl-hibernate and the power button being set up to hibernate, and alt+power button

I assume that the default action when using the power button with or without alt is the systemctl-hiberate.

How can i set it up to use pm-hibernate?

Answer (score 3):

Use the config on [the ARK wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uswsusp#With_systemd) and its debian version [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386837/256774). Then, `systemd` would start using s2disk *(`pm-hibernate` uses s2disk)* to hibernate. This will get`sudo systemctl hibernate` working, and dependent features like *hibernate on **Power** button press* will automatically work.