# Another question about Hibernate in 18.04 (not a duplicate)

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, hibernate, pm-utils

I have a fresh install of 18.04 on a brand-new high-end laptop. Hibernate works using

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

By "works" I mean that it saves the system to disk, and powers down. Upon reboot, the session is resumed at exactly the point I left, including the last terminal command being `pm-hibernate`.

During shutdown it reports:

```
s2disk: Snapshotting system
```

---

I tried to follow various instructions and many SE answers about installing Hibernate as menu option and to trigger upon the power button.

The main one is [this reference on 18.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/) and [this one for 17.10](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-17-10/).

One expects `pm-hibernate` to work. The other expects the command to be

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

But `systemctl hibernate` **does not work** for me. It reports different text output to the console as it shuts down (something about `Alarms can be one month in the future`.) Upon re-boot, it's a full-fresh boot-up, with Chromium complaining it was shutdown ungracefully.

I have a Hibernate option in the shutdown menu [thanks to this plugin](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/) and I have a Hibernate option under Power Settings.

How do I get these GUI options to use the Hibernate which works - the `pm-hibernate` - instead of the broken Hibernate?

[image: Menu Option]
[image: Power Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
[ubuntu 18 hibernation using the power button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056326/ubuntu-18-hibernation-using-the-power-button?rq=1)

and
https://medium.com/@lzcoder/enable-hibernate-on-ubuntu-using-uswsusp-s2disk-ae0b71862eb5

In summary:

```
# [terminal] initial basic steps
sudo apt install uswsusp                  # working hibernate
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell   # for button

# [chrome] to activate in chrome
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/#

# [terminal] modify this file 
cd /lib/systemd/system
sudo gedit systemd-hibernate.service 

# to copy and add to file, leaving only this service
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStartPre=-/bin/run-parts -v -a pre /lib/systemd/system-sleep
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/s2disk
ExecStartPost=-/bin/run-parts -v --reverse -a post /lib/systemd/system-sleep

Source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/

# [terminal] create file to allow button in menu

sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla

#add to file
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes

# [terminal] reload services
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```