# Hibernate does not work Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, suspend, hibernate

Using an IBM ThinkPad with dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 (though mostly just use Ubuntu). After carefully following the advice from these articles:

- [Add ‘Hibernate’ Option in Power Menu in Ubuntu 18.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/)
- [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Enable Hibernate in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031633/enable-hibernate-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

I am still unable to get hibernate to work. The following steps have been done:

1) From Terminal, tried `sudo systemctl hibernate`. This returned

```
`Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported`
```

2) Entered the BIOS and disabled `Secure Boot`

3) Increased the swap file size from 2GB to 28GB (more than my RAM) using:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=28
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo (this just confirms the size)
```

4) Rebooted and again tried `sudo systemctl hibernate`. No error is returned and it appears to work. The computer powers off, the power light flashes and then goes dead. On power up, all open windows are lost and only the desktop is displayed (ie. like a standard reboot).

5) Confirmed that the `BTRFS` file system is not in use using `mount` and `sudo blkid`.

How to get hibernate working? Need to be able to close the lid of my laptop and know I'm not going to lose everything!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @AndrewHarris: Unfortunately never solved this. Have since moved onto another laptop (not Ubuntu), and the old laptop was handed back.